# How to edit an existing item in InfoPath Web Part with SharePoint 2013

Tags: infopath, 2013, query-string

I have a page with nothing on it but a Infopath Form WebPart which I want to use to be able to edit an existing item in a SharePoint list. I have the ID of the item being passed in on the query string but I don't see a way to have the InfoPath form use this to populate the form.

I know it can do this since that is the default action of editing an item directly from the list but does anyone know how they accomplish this?

Comment: Can you explain why you don't want to use the default display form, but a different page showing the display form? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to be able to show the same list item in different info path forms. IE one for initial creation, one for updating, one for the director to review, one for looking back on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to be able to show the same list item in different info path
>   forms. IE one for initial creation, one for updating, one for the
>   director to review, one for looking back on.

Theoretically, this should have been controlled through GUI of Infopath Webpart properties pop-up dialog that has "Views:" drop-down list but practically it has always only one choice:

- Edit item (default)

as well as it should have been possible to identify and change corresponding changes through code....

I believe I tried to clear this question on msdn forum:

- [How to change the type of infopath form received through "Get Form From" connection of web parts?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-IE/sharepointcustomizationprevious/thread/6f6530c8-6dc8-486f-9815-e4faa00d0163)

but with no success. Might be you will have more luck with it and share with it here...

Though, that link should answer your main question "How to edit an existing item in InfoPath Web part". Also, you can find helpful:

- [Passing ID to display InfoPath form](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointcustomizationprevious/thread/2ba19849-2504-4991-9073-0c55422c61ce/)

**Update (addressing comments):**
I referenced query string filter webpart only from the point of view how to edit Infopath webpart, namely, through its connector:

- clicking Web Part menu of the Infopath web Part > Connections > Send form to
  as well as mentioned properties of a webpart.

These are features commonly available for any kind of a web part in Sharepoint WebPart pages and any published to Sharepoint Infopath form is available as a webpart. And according to "Applies to: SharePoint Online Enterprise (E3 & E4), SharePoint Server 2013 Enterprise" of [Use the InfoPath Form Web Part](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-help/use-the-infopath-form-web-part-HA102770988.aspx), I see it is the same in 2013

If you do not have Enterprise Sharepoint Server, then there is no sense to discuss features, available only through enterprise Sharepoint Server like Infopath browser forms and web parts. What your question is about

Comment: Thanks for the response but I am trying to do this in sharepoint 2013 which doesn't have the query string filter webpart. Also looking at the editifs.aspx page there is no hidden list web part so there must be a way to pass those parameters to infopath directly. Any ideas?

Comment: This got me close, I ended up downloading this web part: http://www.simego.com/Blog/2008/01/sharepoint-quer which let me pass the query filter to a list view and then get the data for the info path web part. I don't understand why they removed the filter web parts in 2013

Comment: Turns out 2013 does have the query string filter web part, I just needed to enable enterprise features for the site.

Comment: Have you read my comment? I did not mean to use query string filter webpart. That was just occasonal reference I found as example to illustrate how to configure Infopath web part at large

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is what people are looking for but i edited a web part infopath form successfully (without the infopath form file) directly within sharepoint 2013, by doing the following:

- Navigate to the library where the submitted forms exist (need to be
  in internet explorer to do this)
- Go to library settings> advanced settings.
- Click on '(edit template)'.
- Make the changes required, 'save' (anywhere on pc, it doesn't
  matter), then publish.