# PreSaveAction function not working in infopath 2010 form

Tags: infopath, submit

Below script is working fine in sharepoint default form while submit form but not in infopath form.

```
<script src="/images/prototype.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="images/SPUtility.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

function PreSaveAction()
{
    if(my condition)
     return true;
    else
     return false;      
}
```

How to prevent submit in infopath form if my condition is false?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is the extension of a file which you called Infopath form and in which you have inserted this code? Is it .XSL, .XML, XSN, .ASPX, ...? Where and in which context? Which type of Infopath form?

Comment: I'm using infopath form for sharepoint list. not default form.
i have put content editor webpart and called js file for check validations.
if my js return false then form should not be saved.

Comment: It is possible to do this codeless - with rules. If you want to do it through js, then you obviously should reconsider your requirements and probably your understanding what is  Infopath for and how it is used

Comment: it's not posible using rules. because i want to do some operations before submit form.

Comment: So, do it from Infopath code behind. If you still want to do it externally, in ASPX,then this question is not related to Infopath

Answer (score 3):

Please ask one question per post...  Both are really duplicates to already asked and answered before questions

Infopath 2010 supports code-behind development only in C#.NET or VB.NET (2.0 or 2005), after installing VSTA (Visual Studio Tools for Applications) [as part of Microsoft Office setup](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/58228/8319) and except [Sharepoint List Forms in which code-behind is not supported at all by Infopath](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/44168/8319). Javascript is not supported since Infopath 2003.

If to speak about usage of published Infopath forms as webparts in Infopath Web Part Pages, please check [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/59290/8319).
And if to call external javascript from Infopath form, using NotifyHost, check msdn series of article: "Open a SharePoint Modal Dialog from an InfoPath Form: Part 1 of 5 (Vivek Soni)":

- [Part 1](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/05/17/open-a-sharepoint-modal-dialog-from-an-infopath-form-part-1-of-5.aspx), [Part 2](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/05/18/open-a-sharepoint-modal-dialog-from-an-infopath-form-part-2-of-5.aspx), [Part 3](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/05/18/open-a-sharepoint-modal-dialog-from-an-infopath-form-part-3-of-5.aspx), [Part 4](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/05/20/open-a-sharepoint-modal-dialog-from-an-infopath-form-part-4-of-5.aspx), [Part 5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/05/21/open-a-sharepoint-modal-dialog-from-an-infopath-form-part-5-of-5.aspx)

> How to prevent submit in infopath form if my condition is false?

Please check [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/43267/8319)